# Cyclic Dependency on Swift

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I have 2 different packages created with swift package manager and they are both dependent to each other. When I add dependency to both of them I had an error: "cyclic dependency declaration found ". But I have to add dependency to both of the packages.

Comment: No, you need to refactor your code.

Comment: either make one package depend on the other one way, or extract a common dependency into third package, and make the other two packages dependent on that common package.

Comment: Please share some code to help us understand how the packages are depend to each other and help you sort it out.